# Navigation based iPhone app using thumbnails

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been searching the internet for quite some time and didn't find anything useful.
I want to make a basic app for the iPhone using simple views and hierarchical data nothing too fancy. The only problem is that I can't seem to find any tutorial that makes the first/main view like a thumbnail gallery that leads to other views.

To clear it a bit up:
I want my first view to be a 2D array of thumbnails and a little text below each of these thumbnails. When I click on a thumbnail it takes me to a sub-view containing more detailed info and options.

So is there any relatively painless way to make something like this using Table Views or something like that or do I have to make a custom view with methods to populate it as my heart pleases.

Please take note that I want to avoid any third party libraries like Three20 or similar.

Thanks

Comment: I'll leave the question open for the next couple hours if somebody has other suggestions or ideas. If not slev gets the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure I understand, you want to make an application that acts similar to the Contacts on the iPhone?  In other words, a list that when an item is clicked will take you to a new view with detailed information about the clicked item?  But in your case, you want an image next to/above the text?

In either case, you will want to use a tableView.  If you want an image beside the text, just set the `imageView.image` property of the cell to a corresponding image.  If you want a different layout, however, you will need to create your own custom `UITableViewCell`, which is not a hard task at all.  [Here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) is a tutorial on how to create a custom cell using IB.  It can also be done programmatically if you prefer to do it that way.  I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, since I need a more "dynamic" UI (variable number of Thumbnails and menu items) I'll have to make a custom tailored View. The link you provided is a nice starting point though.

Comment: My pleasure.  If you need a variable number of items and thumbnails, it sounds like you will indeed want to create custom cells.  You should be able to change the size and style as needed, though creating different genereal templates for the cells might be a good idea to.  Then perhaps create an `NSObject` file for your cell information (or consider using Core Data) so that you can quickly grab the information you need to fill the content of the individual cells.  Hopefully that's not too vague, but that should make your life a good bit easier and keep you from having to hand-code each cell

Comment: Core Data is out of question for me since the app will have a rather big amount of data (images and text) ~120-150mb. So I've made a custom data holder so going custom all the way seems to be my only option. Anyways thanks for the guidelines.

Comment: Any time.  Sorry to hear you had to go with a custom data holder, but creating the cells shouldn't be too hard, especially if they're generic enough that they can be reused for each object.  Then at least you can simply call it and assign the proper values